# Why does the real part of permittivity (according to lorentz model) converge to 1 faster in materials with less plasma frequency?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, polarization, dielectric, metamaterials

according to  Lorentz oscillator model that describes optical responses of materials we get a complex permittivity which its real part is given by

[image]

we can see that the real part converges to 1 at high frequencies , now I plotted the function of the real part at different plasma frequencies (other constants didn't change) and found that those with less plasma frequencies tend to converge faster than those with higher plasma frequencies , can anybody give me a physical explanation of why this happens?